# Access a php global in twig template

Tags: php, templates, twig, config, global

I need to access a global defined with php function define(MY_GLOBAL, 'foo'); in a twig template.
I can't use the detour $app['twiq']->addGlobal(); because I'm in my config file

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a global, that's a constant. For accessing constants, there's the aptly named [`constant()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html):

```
{{ constant('MY_GLOBAL') }}
```

Comment: Thanks and do u know how do I get this constant in a controller ?

Comment: Uhm... simply `MY_GLOBAL`!?